# Problema con herencia en c#

Tags: c#, herencia

Tengo la siguiente consigna: Hace una Vista programador (nombre, apellido, horas trabajadas, boton calcular()) El metodo calcular devuelve el resultado en una vista 2 de programador(nombre, apellido - solo lectura). (Valor hora e incentivo en la clase como atributo privado - para calcular sueldo: valorHora*horasTrabajadas+incentivo).
Tengo que hacer una herencia entre Empleado y EmpleadoProgramador.

empleado.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Empresa.Models
{
    public abstract class Empleado
    {
        protected string Nombre { set; get; }
        protected string Apellido { set; get; }
        public Empleado() { }

        public Empleado(string Nombre, string Apellido)
        {
            Nombre = this.Nombre;
            Apellido = this.Apellido;
        }

        /*  public abstract float CalcularSueldo();
          } */

    }
}
```

EmpleadoProgramador.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Empresa.Models
{
    public class EmpleadoProgramador : Empleado
    {
        private float SueldoFijo { set; get; }

       // public EmpleadoProgramador() { }

        private void EmpleadoProgramador(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas,float valorHora, float incentivo) : base(Nombre, Apellido)
        {
            horas = 30;
            valorHora = 50;
            incentivo = 5000;
            CalcularSueldo(Nombre, Apellido, horas, valorHora, incentivo);
        }




        public float CalcularSueldo(horas, valorHora, incentivo)
        {

            float SueldoFijo = valorHora * horas + incentivo;
            return SueldoFijo;
        }


    }
}
```

En `private void EmpleadoProgramador(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas,float valorHora, float incentivo) : base(Nombre, Apellido)` me dice que "los nombres de los miembros no pueden coincidir con los tipos envolventes" y no me acepta el : para la herencia, tampoco me acepta el método CalcularSueldo() porque dice que no hay sobrecarga.
Tambien en

```
public float CalcularSueldo(horas, valorHora, incentivo)
{   

   float SueldoFijo = valorHora * horas + incentivo;
    return SueldoFijo;
}
```

me dice que no existen esos tipos. Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas noches chaval,

Para el "problema": **los nombres de los miembros no pueden coincidir con los tipos envolventes**, Los miembros de una clase o una estructura no pueden tener el mismo nombre que la clase o la estructura, a menos que el miembro sea un constructor, cuidado con eso. El siguiente método tiene el mismo nombre de la clase en este caso. Si lo que deseas es que dicho método sea un constructor, debes quitar el "void" (valor de retorno) dado que un constructor no devuelve valor alguno:

```
private void EmpleadoProgramador(string Nombre, string Apellido, int horas,float valorHora, float incentivo) : base(Nombre, Apellido)
    {
        horas = 30;
        valorHora = 50;
        incentivo = 5000;
        CalcularSueldo(Nombre, Apellido, horas, valorHora, incentivo);
    }
```

Comment: Algo más que quisiera sugerir, y es que uses método abstracto para calcular el sueldo, creo que es lo ideal!

Comment: es un constructor por defecto. no entiendo en el método que me dice 
Error CS1501 Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'CalcularSueldo' toma 5 argumentos.

Comment: ya lo solucion, gracia

Answer (score 0):

El erro en el método `public float CalcularSueldo(horas, valorHora, incentivo)` creo que se debe a que la definición está mal.
Debería ser:

```
public float CalcularSueldo(int horas, float valorHora, float incentivo)
```

Eso sería en cuanto a la sintaxis, para aplicar herencia te puede servir este artículo: [Herencia (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173149.aspx)